# What does "fortune" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Can someone help me understand the meaning of this Lorenzo Ghiberti's quote:

> “Only he who has learned everything, can fearlessly despise the changes of fortune.”

I have some doubts about the meaning of the word "fortune" here. Does it mean "fate", "destiny,... or "wealth"?

Comment: I think it means "destiny" given the sentence you provide.

Answer (score 1):

**fortune**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/73751?rskey=0sdWyd&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

> a. chance, happenstance, or luck, regarded as a cause of events and
>   changes in men's affairs. Often (after Latin) personified as a
>   goddess, ‘the power supposed to distribute the lots of life according
>   to her own humour’ (Johnson); her emblem is a wheel, betokening
>   vicissitude.

As in:

> “Only he who has learned everything, can fearlessly despise the
>   changes of in the affairs of men.”

or

> “Only he who has learned everything, can fearlessly despise the
>   [vicissitudes](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/223184?redirectedFrom=vicissitude#eid) of life.”